# Smooth Scrolling in GridView from bitmaps in database

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap

I have some images in database and I'd like to show them in `GridView`.

Here is my function for get `Bitmaps` from Database

```
public Bitmap getBitmaps(String tableName, int id, int index) {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE "
                + BaseColumns._ID + " = " + id;
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        byte[] byteArray = cursor.getBlob(index);

        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    }
```

And here is my `GridView`'s Adapter

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                //..
            } else {

            //..
            }

            new AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, Bitmap>() {
                private ViewHolder v;

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
                    v = params[0];    

                    return getBitmaps(tableName, id,index);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

                    super.onPostExecute(result);

                    if (v.position == position) {
                        v.image.setImageBitmap(result);
                    }
                }
            }.execute(viewHolder);
            return convertView;
        }
```

Now I have a problem:

For example I have more than 20 items in my `GridView`. When I scroll down to the end of the list it takes 1 or 2 seconds (or more seconds if list get larger) to load the image of a certain position . Same problem appears if I scroll to the top of the list .

Now how can I optimize my code to scroll smooth and fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change your approach for example create a ImageLoader class and pass your request to it. in the ImageLoader create an in memory cache [LRUCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) then if the request is in the cache just return it if it is not load from DB and then set it for `viewholder`. for each `viewholder` set a tag that is equal to its position then when you have load it check the tag of `viewholder` and see if it is equal to the image position that you have just loaded or not, if it is equal set the image else that means the view holder has  been recycled. Keep `viewholder` reference as a `weakreference` and whenever your image is ready check the holder to see if it is null or not.

further optimization also possible and that is for example recycling the `bitmap`, you can read the document to see how it is implemented.

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: I got null pointer by scrolling if i change refrence of viewHolder to weakreference(i mean viewHolder in getView).Any ideas?

Comment: I do not know what you are doing but for simplicity just use your old approach and add `LRUCache`. that means before asking to load from DB first check the cache and when you have loaded any images add it to the cache.

Comment: Thanks, it solve by changing reference of `private ViewHolder v` to weakrefrence.